# What does the output of Seq2SeqTrainer predict.predictions refer to and how to get T5 generated summaries

Tags: huggingface

I am working on a T5 Summarizer and would like to know what the output for trainer.predict.predictions refer to. Also, I saw that we would have to use argmax to get the generated summary but my results for predict.predictions returns a nested array. How do I know which array to use?

These are my codes:

```
# Train trainer
from transformers import T5ForConditionalGeneration, Seq2SeqTrainingArguments, Seq2SeqTrainer

model = T5ForConditionalGeneration.from_pretrained('t5-base')

output_dir = 'output2'

# fine-tune model using the transformers.Trainer API
training_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    num_train_epochs=6,
    per_device_train_batch_size=8,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    eval_accumulation_steps=1, 
    prediction_loss_only=True, 
    learning_rate=4e-5,
    evaluation_strategy='steps', 
    save_steps=1000,
    save_total_limit=1, 
    eval_steps=1000, 
    load_best_model_at_end=True,
    metric_for_best_model="rouge1", 
    predict_with_generate=True,
    push_to_hub=False,
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(
    model=model,
    args=training_args,
    train_dataset=train_dataset,
    eval_dataset=val_dataset
)

trainer.train()
```

```
#Evaluate Trainer/ get summaries
pred_args = Seq2SeqTrainingArguments(
    output_dir=output_dir,
    per_device_eval_batch_size=8,
    eval_accumulation_steps=1
)

trainer = Seq2SeqTrainer(model=model, args=pred_args)

prediction= trainer.predict(val_dataset)
preds = prediction.predictions
labels = prediction.label_ids
```

preds returns a nested array. I'm not sure which part of the array I should use argmax on.
[output of trainer.predict.predictions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9zTE.png)